# How to insert into a table while ignoring fields with no data?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I wan't to insert data to a table but not all fields are required to be filled some are just optional.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_Records_of_Violation(Serial_Number,Badge,Rank,Lastname,Firstname,Middlename,Qualifier,Gender,Birthdate,Date_Ent_Svc,Address,MotherUnit,Unit,Date_of_Commission,Reporting_Officer,Report_to_Supervisor,Approving_Authority,Punishment,Remarks,Violation1) VALUES ('" & Me.Serial_Number & "','" & Me.Badge & "','" & Me.Rank & "','" & Me.Lastname & "','" & Me.Firstname & "','" & Me.Middlename & "','" & Me.Qualifier & "','" & Me.Gender & "','" & Me.Birthdate & "','" & Me.Date_Ent_Svc & "','" & Me.Address & "','" & Me.MotherUnit & "','" & Me.Unit & "','" & Me.Date_of_Commission & "','" & Me.Reporting_Officer & "','" & Me.Report_to_Supervisor & "','" & Me.Approving_Authority & "','" & Me.Punishment & "','" & Me.Remarks & "'," & Me.Violation1 & ")"

MsgBox "Record has been updated", vbInformation, "Record Information"
```

I want that even if one of the field is empty it would be saved in my table.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but wouldn't a parameterized query be better for this? That way you can just provide nulls for anything that's missing but not required.

Comment: It also looks like you're using a form. So why not just bind the form to the table? Then you can do more with less code and it'll work just the way you need it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The table  tbl_Records_of_Violation  has 20 columns of data being inserted by this command.

Each of those 20 columns should be defined as Nullable,

and each of the screen values  (Me.xxx) needs to have valid data or nulls.